# ngbAccordion class not defined with ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a simple accordion style using Angular 2 and ng2-bootstrap. I'm using the Angular2 Quickstart files as the starting point and modified the files to add ng2-bootstrap, bootstrap.css. The index.html, app.module.ts, app.component.ts, and app.component.html files are listed below. The ng2-bootstrap 'Alert' functions correctly, but I receive the following error for the 'Accordion' element:

```
zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbAccordion" ("
<br> ......
```

Any ideas on the cause of the error and potential fixes?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Import bootstrap here -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({

  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot()
     ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<alert type="success" dismissible="true">
    Well Done!
</alert>
<br>

<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel>
    <template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </template>
    <template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're confusing the things...

You're importing `ng2-bootstrap` lib and trying to use `ng-bootstrap` components.

See [**`ng2-bootstrap#accordion`**](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/accordion) and [**`ng-bootstrap#accordtion`**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion).

Comment: Thanks this fixes the problem. I'm finding it very confusing to find the correct mix of Angular2 with bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap and UI-Angular. In addition to this accordion problem, I'm particularly struggling to apply the bootstrap flexbox concept. Column offsets seem to work, but options like justify-content-end do not. Thanks again for the help.